# Error when trying to use File inside ${ForEachIn}?

Tags: nsis

I have the following code block inside the .onInit function of my NSIS script.

```
; Split the supplied artifacts array. 
nsArray::Split ARTIFACT_ARRAY "${ARTIFACTS}" ";"  

${ForEachIn} ARTIFACT_ARRAY $R0 $R1  
   File ${IVY_ROOT}\"$R1"
${Next}
```

The ${ARTIFACTS} is a passed in property from ANT at NSIS compile time and is basically a comma seperated list of files.  When I attempt to compile the script I get the error below.

```
 [exec] File: "C:\My_Workspaces\WEnDL\\deployments\ivy\"$R1"" -> no files found.
 [exec] Usage: File [/nonfatal] [/a] ([/r] [/x filespec [...]] filespec [...] |
 [exec]    /oname=outfile one_file_only)
 [exec] Error in script "C:\My_Workspaces\WEnDL\/deployments/selections.nsis" on line 394 -- aborting creation process
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: The quotes on the file path are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use variables in `File` instructions because variables are only evaluated on the end-users system. The same is true for plug-ins. You need to stick with ${defines} and the instructions starting with `!` when parsing at compile-time.

The best option is letting your build system generate a .nsh with the `File` instructions if possible:

```
Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
!include "generatedfilelist.nsh"
SectionEnd
```

Another option is to call external tools or batch-files with `!system` and let them parse the list and generate the .nsh.

Finally, in NSIS v3 it might be possible to pull this off with macro recursion and `!searchparse`+`!searchreplace` but the available recursion depth is limited so it might not work depending on the number of files in your list.